# database structure

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational

I'm building a gambling-related website where people can be on soccer fixtures (matches).
A fixture ends up with a result: home win - draw - away win. I have one table for teams and one table for fixtures and another for bets.  The fixtures table has a home team and an away team. But how do I model a draw bet? It's easy to have the bet table refer to the fixture and refer to the team. But a draw?

Comment: The bet doesn't refer to a team; the bet refers to the outcome of a fixture.  You don't record the team that will win; you record the outcome of the match.  Don't forget you'll need customers and that it is customers who place bets.

Comment: Also, in the classic (UK) pools, there is a distinction between a score-draw (eg 1-1) and a no-score-draw (ie 0-0).  Just an FYI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most basic system:

3 tables, one for teams, one for fixtures and one for bets. Outcomes are represented by:

0 => Draw, 1 => Home win, 2 => Away win

Teams:

```
id | name
-----------------
 1 | Some team 
 2 | Some team
 3 | Some team
```

Fixtures:

```
id | home team | away team | result
--------------------------------------
 1 |         1 |         3 |        0
 2 |         2 |         3 |        2
 3 |         1 |         3 |        1
```

Bets:

```
id | fixture   | outcome    
---------------------------
 1 |         1 |         0 
 2 |         2 |         1 
 3 |         1 |         3
```